# Insert a row for each array item -- for many arrays

Tags: postgresql

Say you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
x  integer,
y  integer,
);
```

And multiple rows of the form `x, [y1, y2, ...]`:

```
x ys
1 [2,3]
4 [5,6,7]
```

There might be an arbitrary but non-zero (or non-nil) amount of `ys` in each row. `x` always non-nil.

How to insert such that you end up with a row for each x, y pair, that is:

```
x y
1 2
1 3
4 5
4 6
4 7
```

Comment: Where do the arrays come from?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name by manual specification in the SQL statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unnest() the arrays:

```
insert into tab (x,y)
select v.x, t.y
from (
 values 
   (1, array[2,3]), 
   (4, array[5,6,7])
) as v(x,ya) 
  cross join unnest(v.ya) as t(y)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a097339fd5e48e390cf9413cd8c0831)